# Cannot access HTTPS websites after OSX El Capitan upgrade

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan

After upgrading to OSX El Capitan, I can no longer securely access any webpage with a HTTPS protocol, such as online banking or online retail checkouts. This appears to happen in all browsers (attempted Chrome and Safari) on OSX El Capitan.

Accessing a URL with a "https://" protocol in Chrome produces a warning screen that reads "Your connection is not private", with a "Back to safety" button. While I can circumvent this screen through the "Advanced" options, that seems like a bad idea. Curious if anyone else has encountered this issue while upgrading to El Cap, and if so, what they did about it.

Comment: I believe this would have been a better fit on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this support forum here, which was extremely helpful:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7254070?start=0&tstart=0

While my individual certificate settings were already configured as that post describes, I did find some invalidated VeriSign certificates that needed to be deleted. My solution:

- Launch Keychain Access app.
- Go to "My Certificates" in the left rail. Step through each certificate listing in the right-hand panel, and look for a little red "X" with an "invalid certificate" notice in the description. Delete invalid certificates from Keychain Access.
- Go to "Certificates" in the left rail, and again follow the above process of deleting invalid certificates marked with a red "X".
- Quit Keychain Access, and restart.

The issue seems to be that El Capitan has much tighter security controls, so older certificates with weaker security are rejected by the operating system, but not deleted. Then when accessing a HTTPS website that you've been to before, the existing certificate is recognized but seen as invalid. By deleting all invalidated certificates, these certificates will be reissued the next time you visit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its related to El Capitan upgrade.

Are your Time and date settings proper? Sometimes that might cause the issue.

Comment: I did come across several mentions of date and time issues while researching the problem. That seems to be another good margin of error to check. In this case, it was indeed the El Capitan upgrade and its changes to Keychain Access security certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to access a login page at https://hsid11.optum.com/ using any browser in El Capitan. System time is updated automatically and the date is correct. I deleted all the expired login certificates but I didn't get a new one when I returned to the login page.

So one other possible reason for a persistent security warning is that El Capitan is more than three years old and is no longer getting security updates.